How to make command to turn off monitor output?
I ran in to a problem, I use two identical monitors one is used exclusively for pc other one is for pc and ps5. Sometimes I want to use just 1 and to pc not to output to thr other one. I am aware you can do it threw settings but it would be nice to have shortcut for it.
If anybody can help I would be realy grateful.
Thanks for helping

If you're using an Xorg session (and not Wayland) then maybe consider using xrandr
For example, my laptop has two displays - eDP which is the internal display panel, and DisplayPort-0 connected to an external monitor:
$ xrandr | grep " connected "
eDP connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 connected primary 2560x2880+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 465mm x 523mm

I can turn the external monitor off like this:
$ xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --off

Which results in the external monitor going off, and the internal one becoming the main display:
$ xrandr | grep " connected "
eDP connected 2880x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 289mm x 186mm
DisplayPort-0 connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

I can even turn the internal (eDP) off, so they're both off:
$ xrandr --output eDP --off
DP connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

I can switch them back on again with --auto:
$ xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --auto
DisplayPort-0 connected primary 2560x2880+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 465mm x 523mm

Put the right combination of them in a script, and drop that in /usr/local/bin and put a shortcut on the desktop, so you can easily get to it. Or map a key to running the script and have a hot key.
